Does my design violate the Liskov Substitution Principle?
I'm working on a Spring Boot application with the following structure for sending messages
public interface MessageService {
  void send(String message);
}

@Component("SendEmailService")
public class SendEmailService implements MessageService {

  @Override
  public void send(String message) {
    System.out.println("SendEmailService");
  }
}

@Component("SendSmsService")
public class SendSmsService implements MessageService {

  @Override
  public void send(String message) {
    System.out.println("SendSms");
  }
}

The application works well, but now I've got a new requirement. Some messages sent by email need a retry mechanism in case of failure. Here's how I implemented this:
public class ExceptionUtils {

  public static void retryOnException(Runnable runnable, int maxRetries, long timeSeed) {
    // Retry logic here
  }
}

@Component("RetryableSendEmailService")
public class RetryableSendEmailService extends SendEmailService {

  @Override
  public void send(String message) {
    ExceptionUtils.retryOnException(() -> super.send(message), 3, 5000);
  }
}

Idea :

I created a new class RetryableSendEmailService that extends
SendEmailService.
If a component needs retry logic, it can inject
RetryableSendEmailService. If not, it can inject SendEmailService.

Concern:
I'm worried that this might violate the Liskov Substitution Principle (LSP) from the SOLID principles. The principle states:

Objects of a superclass shall be replaceable with objects of its
subclasses without breaking the application. This requires subclasses
to behave in the same way as their superclasses.

Questions:

Does adding a retry mechanism in RetryableSendEmailService violate
LSP since it changes the behavior of send by introducing retries?
How can I refactor this code to adhere more closely to SOLID
principles, especially LSP, while still achieving the desired
functionality?


Whether adding a retry "changes the behaviour of send" is really for you to decide. What is send documented to do? If it promises to not retry (which is a weird design), then this would be changing its behaviour. If it only promises to try to send the email, then adding a retry would not change its behaviour. See also: https://stackoverflow.com/q/78364288/5133585

To be able to use retry the following criteria group should be met:

The potentially introduced observable impact is acceptable
The operation can be redone without any irreversible side effect
The introduced complexity is negligible compared to the promised reliability

From the LSP persective the first two are important.
The potentially introduced observable impact is acceptable
With retry it might happen that you send out the exact same message multiple times due to some transient issue.
In other words, your at most once semantic (the code without retry) is changed to at least once (with the retry).
The operation can be redone without any irreversible side effect
As it was said in the previous point it might happen that the messaging provider sends out multiple copies of the same message. OR it has a dedicated de-duplication feature which helps to make the send operation act idempotently. You should be aware of this before you apply retry "blindly".
